# how to display different form views in the same sheet?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Good morning,

I have this parent view (audit form) containing this notebook:

```
<sheet string="Audit">
    <field name="name" required="1"/>
    <field name="reference"/>
    <field name="date" required="1"/>
    <field name="company_id"/>
    <field name="audit_type"/>
    <notebook string="Audit"> 
        <page string="Nonconformities">
            <field name="nonconformity_ids"/>
        </page> 
        <page string="Track Progress">
            <field name="track_progress_ids" nolabel="1" />
        </page> 
    </notebook>
</sheet>
```

The nonconformity model has a many2many relation with the audit form.I just always add new nonconformities, so I don't need to show the nonconfomity list to choose from, what I want is to show directly the nonconformity form inside the nonconformity page, I can't figure how.

Please Help.

Comment: I can't understand your question, but I think you need to use wizards. What means form inside of form? If you want an extra items add them to the form... I cant understand how are you going to show all many2many records with form

Comment: @DachiDarchiashvili My client doesn't want to see the nonconformity list he always needs to add new ones, so instead of clicking on add new item to show nonconformmity list and then click on create button to appear nonconformity popup view, he wants to directly fill the nonconformity form inside of the page in audit form.

Comment: and in this case what is reason of using many2many? make some field with button action and after filling fields using button click function add new records.

Comment: I need a many2many or one2many relation cause I can add nonconformities as many as I want

Comment: ok i understand now what you want. still you cant create as you want (i think), if its good idea for you, add button under that field, and on click it show wizard with your prefered form and from there user can add as many records as he wish

Comment: Yes I tried this, I followed this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907694/open-another-module-form-view-with-button) but I wanted to get rid of the wizard and call the nonconformity form inside the same page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111505/discussion-between-tessnim-and-dachi-darchiashvili).

Comment: First of use one2many instead of many2many, because that is what you need here. Why does it have to be a form in a form (what IIRC isn't possible)? Why not using an editable tree in your form?

Comment: @CZoellner because I want to reduce the number of clicks to reach nonconformity form, and I wanted to be in the same sheet, not a new wizard.

Comment: And why don't use an editable tree view? it will be inside the "above" form view without a wizard or anything.

Comment: @CZoellner because I don't want tree view I want a complete form view. Here's what exactly I want: when I click on 'add an Item' the form appears, I fill my fields and when I click on save, the form disappears and the record is added to the list.

Comment: Yes, that's Odoo's default behaviour. And i don't know a way to have a real embedded form view (without popup).

Answer (score 0):

You can have embedded views inside a `<field>` element.
For example:

```
    <page string="Nonconformities">
        <field name="nonconformity_ids">
            <form>
              <!-- nonconformity fields -->
              <field name="name" />
              <field name="user_id" />
            </form>
        </field>
    </page>
```

Comment: hi @Daniel embedded views inside a <field> not work in case of form view.

Comment: @Daniel Renis It's not working I got parsing errors. and I need to show the nonconformity form with the save button and the workflow menu of nonconformity form.

Comment: This will work. I guess Daniel's fields name and user_id just were examples, so if your model (what's behind nonconformity_ids) doesn't have these fields, you will ofcourse get errors. Problem with this solution: you will get a PopUp like a wizard. You will find a good example in Odoo's addon sale and the form view of sale.order, where a form and tree view are embedded for sale.order.line (field order_line).

Comment: @CZoellner I want to import all the form, I need a way to call it without coping and pasting fields into the audit form.